# Adding sensor data to a list with Python

Tags: python

I am working on a project where I am trying to store sensor data (temperature, humidity, etc.) in a list.  My program is written in python (I am still new to Python).  I will have the sensor sample at various rates.  I want the ten most recent sensor samples to be stored in a list, and an average taken of the ten values.  This will help smooth out the data coming from the sensors.

I am having trouble getting it correctly work the way that I want it though.  My output keeps appending one sensor reading, and only one, to the end of my list.  I want it to keep pushing the old data out and bringing the new data into the list.  For example, if a given sensor has taken only ten samples then the list would look like this [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] , then the 11th sample would come in from the sensor and it would change to [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11] , then the 12th [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] , and so on and so forth.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the code that I am trying to use to append the sensor data to the list, have that list contain only the ten most recent samples, and calculate the moving average of those ten samples periodically.

```
import time
import spidev

def getReading(channel):
  rawData = spi.xfer([1,(8+channel)<<4,0])
  processesData = (rawData[1]&3)<<8)+rawData[2]
  return processedData

voltage = (getReading(7)/1023.0)*3.3
readings = []
reading = round(voltage, 2)
max_samples = 10

def mean(nums):
  return float(sum(nums)) / max(len(nums), 1)

avg = mean(readings)

while True:
  print ('current average = ' , avg)
  print ('readings used for average' , readings)
  
  readings.append(reading) 

  if len(readings) == max_samples:
    readings.pop(0)
  
  print ('readings saved for next time:' , readings)
  
  time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: A [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) with `maxlen` can do that.

Comment: Shouldn't your getReading call be within the loop?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic], and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't the call to getReading be within the loop if you want a new reading each time? Something like:

```
import time
import spidev

def getReading(channel):
  rawData = spi.xfer([1,(8+channel)<<4,0])
  processesData = (rawData[1]&3)<<8)+rawData[2]
  return processedData


readings = []
max_samples = 10

def mean(nums):
  return float(sum(nums)) / max(len(nums), 1)



while True:
  voltage = (getReading(7)/1023.0)*3.3
  reading = round(voltage, 2)
  readings.append(reading) 

  avg = mean(readings)     

  print ('current average = ' , avg)
  print ('readings used for average' , readings)

  if len(readings) == max_samples:
    readings.pop(0)
  
  print ('readings saved for next time:' , readings)
  
  time.sleep(10)
```